# Explicitly showing the finite dimensional distribution of Brownian motion is consistent

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, stochastic-processes

I wish to explicitly prove the family of finite dimensional distributions used to define Brownian motion is consistent. The definition of consistent I am using is taken from *Stochastic analysis and diffusion processes* by Gopinath Kallianpur and Padmanabhan Sundar.

A family of finite dimensional distributions is consistent if the following condition holds:

Let $k \in \mathbb{N}$ and $ 0 \leq t_1 < \ldots < t_k$ be arbitrary. Let $\{B_i\}_{i=1}^k$ be an arbitrary collection of 1-dimensional Borel sets. Then for any $i$ we have,
$$
\mu_{t_1,\ldots,t_k}(B_1 \times \ldots \times B_{i-1} \times \mathbb{R} \times B_{i+1} \times \ldots B_k) = \mu_{t_1,\ldots,t_{i-1},t_{i+1},\ldots,t_k}(B_1 \times \ldots \times B_{i-1} \times B_{i+1} \times \ldots B_k).
$$

For simplicity let $k=2$, $0 \leq t_1 \leq t_2$ and fix an $x \in \mathbb{R}$. Then for any two Borel sets $B_1$ and $B_2$ define,
$$
\mu_{t_1,t_2}(B_1 \times B_2) = \int_{B_1 \times B_2} \frac{\exp(-\frac{|x-y|^2}{2t_1})}{\sqrt{2 \pi t_1}} \cdot \frac{\exp(-\frac{|y-z|^2}{2(t_2-t_1)})}{\sqrt{2 \pi(t_2- t_1)}} d\lambda^2(z, y),
$$
where $d\lambda^2(z ,y)$ is the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}^2$. Now to prove this is consistent we need to show $\mu_{t_1,t_2}(\mathbb{R} \times B_2)=\mu_{t_2}(B_2)$ (the case where $B_2=\mathbb{R}$ is easy). By Fubini's theroem we can write,

\begin{align*}
    \mu_{t_1,t_2}(\mathbb{R} \times B_2) & = \int_{\mathbb{R} \times B_2} \frac{\exp(-\frac{|x-y|^2}{2t_1})}{\sqrt{2 \pi t_1}} \cdot \frac{\exp(-\frac{|y-z|^2}{2(t_2-t_1)})}{\sqrt{2 \pi(t_2- t_1)}} d\lambda^2(z, y)\\
    &= \int_{\mathbb{R}} \int_{B_2} \frac{\exp(-\frac{|x-y|^2}{2t_1})}{\sqrt{2 \pi t_1}} \cdot \frac{\exp(-\frac{|y-z|^2}{2(t_2-t_1)})}{\sqrt{2 \pi(t_2- t_1)}} dz dy.
\end{align*}

My issue is how to evaluate this integral as $y$ appears in both exponents. Am I missing a simple trick? Pretty much every author says this is trivial and leaves it as an exercise. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Edit: To add extra clarity to my question as advised in a comment, I am interested in showing consistency using the explicit densities. The reason for this is that in order to claim existence of Brownian motion you need to explicitly construct the finite dimensional distribution denoted $\mu_{t_1,\ldots,t_k}$ on $\mathbb{R}^k$ and show said construction is consistent. Thus apriori you cannot make any claims about any stochastic process such as $\mathbb{P}(X_{t_1} \in B_1, X_{t_2} \in B_2 )=\mathbb{P}(X_{t_2} \in B_2, X_{t_1} \in B_1 )$, as neither the probability measure or process exist.

Comment: For any $t$, it is sufficient to note that $W_t\in \mathbb{R}$ a.s. Then $P(W_{t_1}\in A_1,W_{t_2}\in \mathbb{R},W_{t_3}\in A_3)=P(W_{t_1}\in A_1,W_{t_3}\in A_3)$.

Comment: Thanks for your comment but this is not what I am asking. When defining Brownian motion you need to construct the desired finite dimensional distribution $\mu_{t_1,\ldots,t_k}$ on $\mathbb{R}^k$ and explicitly show said construction is consistent before you can claim the existence of any stochastic process.  Thus apriori the abstract probability measure $P$ you are referring to does not exist.

Comment: I believe one needs to show consistency using the explicit densities, and this is what I am having trouble with.

Comment: Good: I suggest to add such detail then!

Comment: @Snoop I've added the extra details in the question so I'm more clear! thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came about this computational trick in *Probability and Measure* by Billingsley, example 20.6. Upon setting $x=0$, the trick is to make the substitution $u=y\sqrt{t_2}/\left(\sqrt{t_1(t_2-t_1)}\right)$. After lots of calculations one can show the above integral reduces to,

$$\int_{B_2} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi t_2} }  \int_{\mathbb{R}} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}  \exp\left[-\frac{1}{2}\left(u-\frac{z\sqrt{t_1}}{\sqrt{t_2-t_1}\sqrt{t_2}}\right)^2 -\frac{z^2}{2t_2}\right] du dz.$$
We can now factor out the lone $z^2$ term from the inner integral to obtain,
$$
        \int_{B_2} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi t_2} } \exp(-\frac{z^2}{2t_2}) \int_{\mathbb{R}} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}  \exp\left[-\frac{1}{2}\left(u-\frac{z\sqrt{t_1}}{\sqrt{t_2-t_1}\sqrt{t_2}}\right)^2 \right] du dz.
$$
But the inner integral is equal to one (as it is a density) and so we obtain,
$$
\mu_{t_1,t_2}(\mathbb{R} \times B_2) = \int_{B_2} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi t_2} } \exp(-\frac{z^2}{2t_2})dz = \mu_{t_2}(B_2),
$$
as required.

Answer (score 2):

By definition, $\mu_{t_1, \dots, t_n}$ is the distribution of $(X_1, X_1 + X_2, \dots, X_1 + \dots + X_n)$ where $X_1, \dots, X_n$ are independent with $X_1 \sim N(0, t_1)$, $X_2 \sim N(0, t_2 - t_1)$, $\dots$, $X_n \sim N(t_n - t_{n - 1})$.

You can see that the consistency is implied by the fact that if you have two independent normal random variables, then their sum is normal. This amounts to computing the convolution of the densities and seeing it is a normal density.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, however I'm not sure how this implies $\mu_{t_1,t_2}(\mathbb{R} \times B_2) = \mu_{t_2}(B_2)$ ?

Comment: Write it out: $$\mu_{t_1, t_2}(\mathbb{R} \times B_2) = P(X_1 \in \mathbb{R}, X_1 + X_2 \in B_2) = P(X_1 + X_2 \in B_2).$$ Since $X_1 + X_2 \sim N(0, t_2)$, this is the same as $\mu_{t_2}(B_2)$.

Comment: Apologies, I should of been more clear with my comment. When I asked how this implication holds I meant in terms of the explicit densities as referred to in the question.